# Prove that the function f defined by$f(x)= x^r cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is differentiable at $0$ if $r=2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Prove that the function $f$ defined by $f(x)= x^r cos(\frac{1}{cos})$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is differentiable at $0$ if $r=2$ and not differentiable at $0$ if $r=1$

Comment: What do you mean with $\cos\left(\dfrac 1\cos\right)$?

Comment: I think it's $\cos(1/x)$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Makes sense.

Comment: It is not only differentiable at 0 for r=2, I think it is differentiable for $r\geq 2$. I believe that the exercise should show you that the continuity of a function does not imply that the function is differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start, using the definition of the derivative at a point, we have

$$ f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^r\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-0}{x-0}= \lim_{x\to 0}x^{r-1}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right). $$

Now, check when the above limit exists.

**Note:** The definition of the derivative at a point $x_0$ is given by

> $$ f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}. $$